# Angular: Call a function within the interpolation brackets

Tags: angular, string-interpolation

In my Angular Project i have an class A:

```
export class A {
    id: number;

    public displayName(): string{
       return "a";
    }
```

In my component i have an array of type A, so the component.ts has the line:

```
arrayOfAs: Array<A>;
```

In the component.html i just want to display the number and the result of the string function in a ngFor-loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of arrayOfAs">
    {{element.id}}, {{element.displayName()}}
</div>
```

the id can be displayed, but for the function i get the error:

TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.displayName is not a function

How can i use a function inside the interpolation?

Obviously this is just a shortend version of my real case. Thanks

Comment: Michael pointed out one issue. My guess is that you also are not creating instances of your class (you have no constructor). You are just telling the type, like you also say in your question. Anyway, you should avoid calling functions/methods in template, especially not inside a *ngFor. It'll be triggered on each change detection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `a.displayName()` when the variable is bound to the name `element`. Try `element.displayName()`

Otherwise ensure that the array contains true instances of class `A` as suggested in comments

Comment: The a.displayName() was just a typo. Your second point helped, thanks.